# count Json data based on two field values javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, typescript

on page load on an angular component I do a get request like this:

```
 private getData() {
    const url = 'http...';
    const data= this.http.get(url).map( res => res.json());
    return data;
 }
```

and I get this result:

```
[
{
id: 1,
type: "science",
action: "on",
name: "title 1",
frequency: 10,
author: null,
},
{
id: 3,
type: "thriller",
action: "off",
name: "Programming",
frequency: 60,
author: 1515202398191,
},
{
id: 4,
type: "article",
action: "pause",
name: "Stories about life",
frequency: 60,
author: 1515202398191,
},
{
id: 5,
type: "science",
action: "on",
name: "Lorem Ipsum",
frequency: 60,
author: 1515202398191,
},
{
id: 6,
type: "science",
action: "off",
name: "Testing",
frequency: 60,
author: 1515202398191,
},
{
id: 8,
type: "science",
action: "on",
name: "Programming",
frequency: 60,
author: 1515202398191,
}
]
```

Inside on the array I have different items, all of them have `type` and `action` which have values. I want to count the item that have same values for `type` and `action` so I'll be able to get some stats  like:

```
[{"type":"science", action:"on", count: 3},
 {"type":"science", action:"off", count: 1},
 {"type":"thriller", action:"off", count: 1},
 {"type":"article", action:"pause", count: 1},
]
```

I started to do something, but I'm not sure how can I do this

```
stats: any;
 function countArr(array){
      var array= [];
      var count = 0;
      array.forEach( function(currentItem){

         array.forEach( function(item){
         // check if 
         if(item.type == currentItem.type && item.action == currentItem.action){
                count++;
             }
           });
           var itemJson = {'type':currentItem.type, 'action':currentItem.action, 'count':count };  
           array.push(itemJson);
      });

    }

private getData() {
        const url = 'http...';
        const data= this.http.get(path).map( res => res.json());
        this.stats = countArr(data);
        return data;
     }
```

Comment: easy to do with a reduce/find combo - but how do you expect `{"type":"thriller", action:"on", count: 0},` ... how can you count something that isn't in the input? e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/Lg54er4z/1/

Comment: I updated the expected array so basically I deleted that

Comment: ahh, didn't see the edited version :p

Answer (score 0):

Try this Example -

```js
var data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        type: "science",
        action: "on",
        name: "title 1",
        frequency: 10,
        author: null,
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        type: "thriller",
        action: "off",
        name: "Programming",
        frequency: 60,
        author: 1515202398191,
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        type: "article",
        action: "pause",
        name: "Stories about life",
        frequency: 60,
        author: 1515202398191,
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        type: "science",
        action: "on",
        name: "Lorem Ipsum",
        frequency: 60,
        author: 1515202398191,
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        type: "science",
        action: "off",
        name: "Testing",
        frequency: 60,
        author: 1515202398191,
    },
    {
        id: 8,
        type: "science",
        action: "on",
        name: "Programming",
        frequency: 60,
        author: 1515202398191,
    }
];
function getCount() {
    var countData = [];
    data.forEach(function (item, index) {
        var existingItem = countData.find(function (countItem) {
            return item.type === countItem.type &&
                item.action === countItem.action;
        });
        if (existingItem) {
            existingItem.count++;
        }
        else {
            existingItem = {
                type: item.type,
                action: item.action,
                count: 1
            };
            countData.push(existingItem);
        }
    });
    return countData;
}
console.log(getCount());
```

Typescript equivalent -

```
let data: Array<any> = [
    {
        id: 1,
        type: "science",
        action: "on",
        name: "title 1",
        frequency: 10,
        author: null,
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        type: "thriller",
        action: "off",
        name: "Programming",
        frequency: 60,
        author: 1515202398191,
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        type: "article",
        action: "pause",
        name: "Stories about life",
        frequency: 60,
        author: 1515202398191,
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        type: "science",
        action: "on",
        name: "Lorem Ipsum",
        frequency: 60,
        author: 1515202398191,
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        type: "science",
        action: "off",
        name: "Testing",
        frequency: 60,
        author: 1515202398191,
    },
    {
        id: 8,
        type: "science",
        action: "on",
        name: "Programming",
        frequency: 60,
        author: 1515202398191,
    }
]

function getCount() {

    let countData: Array<any> = [];

    data.forEach((item, index) => { 
        let existingItem: any = countData.find((countItem) => {
            return item.type === countItem.type &&
                item.action === countItem.action;
        });
        if (existingItem) {
            existingItem.count++;
        } else {
            existingItem = {
                type: item.type,
                action: item.action,
                count: 1
            };
            countData.push(existingItem);
        }
    });     

    return countData;

}

console.log(getCount());
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it this way:

```
var res = []
// data is your initial array
data.forEach((item) => {
    const result = res.find(x => x.type === item.type && x.action === item.action)
    if (result) result.count += 1
    else res.push({type: item.type, action: item.action, count: 1})
})
```

Comment: but I need to take also action value  if it is on, off or anything?

Comment: which is completely different to result asked for

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Answer fixed now.